# python 2.7: differing attributes

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I just started to use (=learn) Python 2.7. My current concern is focused on extracting information from XML files. So far xml.etree.ElementTree got me quite far. I am now stuck with an "KeyError". The reason - as far as I understand it - are elements with differing attributes.

Crucial part of the (much bigger) XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>

<XMLFILE>
  <datasources>
    <datasource caption='Sheet1 (ExcelSample)'>
      <connection class='excel-direct' filename='~\SomeExcel.xlsx' .....>
        ......
      </connection>
      <column header='Unit Price' datatype='real' name='[Calculation_1]'     role='measure' type='quantitative'>
        <calculation class='calculation' formula='Sum(Profit)/Sum(Sales)' />
      </column>
      <column datatype='integer' name='[Sales]' role='measure' type='quantitative' user:auto-column='numrec'>
        <calculation class='trial' formula='1' />
      </column>
    </datasource>
  </datasources>
  ........
</XMLFILE>
```

My Python code works fine for extracting datatype and name, i.e. attributes that exist in both columns:

```
for cal in xmlfile.findall('datasources/datasource/column'):
    dt= cal.attrib[ 'datatype' ]
    nm= cal.attrib[ 'name' ]
    print 'Column name:', dt, '    ', 'datatype:', nm
```

result:

```
Column name: Calculation_1,    datatype:real
Column name: Sales,    datatype:integer
```

However if I use cal.attrib['header'] Python 2.7. prints

```
"KeyError: 'header'
```

Question: How to tell Python 2.7. to produce the desired output:

```
Calculation "Unit Price": Sum(Profit)/Sum(Sales)
```

More precisely what Python should do: " for all (= if there are more than only one like in the above example) columns that contain the attribute 'header' print the output

```
header: Unit Price
    formula: Sum(Profit)
header: Sales per day in month
    formula: Sales / count(days(month))
```

(Note: to show a more complete desired output I added another column that's not in my example yet)

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use XPath *predicate* expression to filter element by certain criteria i.e filter `column` element that has `header` attribute : `column[@header]` *. So your `for` loop will look about like this :

```
for cal in xmlfile.findall('datasources/datasource/column[@header]'):
    print "header: " + cal.attrib["header"]
    print "    formula: " + cal.find('calculation').attrib["formula"]
```

*) Notice that `@attribute_name` syntax is used to reference XML attribute in XPath.

---

Instead, if you mean to iterate through *all* `column` regardless it has `header` attribute or not, but only print header attribute value when the `column` has the attribute, then you can achieve that using simple `if` block, something like this :

```
if "header" in cal.attrib:
    print "header: " + cal.attrib["header"]
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. Although python now does not give an Error anymore, it unfortunately prints nothing at all anymore ....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the "BeautifullSoup" (bs4) module instead of "xml.etree"

Take a look at [Python BeautifulSoup XML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071696/python-beautifulsoup-xml-parsing) and [Extracting properly data with bs4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32702856/extracting-properly-data-with-bs4)

Answer (score 0):

KeyError is Python's way of telling you that the attribute you requested was not found in that element. This is ok, chances are your findall xpath is pulling in a few elements that don't have "header" attributes. Since you are only interested in those that fall under your search AND happen to have a "header" attribute attached to them, you can do the following:

```
for cal in xmlfile.findall('datasources/datasource/column'):
    try:
        header = cal.attrib["header"]
        #Do something with the header
        print header
    except KeyError:
        #This is where you end up if the element doesn't have a 'header' attribute
        #You shouldn't have to do anything with this 'cal' element
```

Sure, you could check if the header exists first, but after using python for some time I think this method is simpler.